# Como combinar 3 imagenes en forma de Y

Tags: css, html5, img

Me gustaría poner en una pagina web, 3 imágenes que se muestren en forma de triángulos (como una Y) y que arriba de cada una tenga un titulo, ya que cuando se pinche una de ellas redirija a un link en concreto.

Esta es la idea que tengo como quiero que se muestren
[image: Esta es la idea que tengo como quiero que se muestren]

Mi código hasta ahora

```css
#arriba2 {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 50vw solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 border-right: 50vw solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 border-top: 60vh solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
 border-image-repeat: stretch;
 /* border-image: url(../../assets/img/arriba.png) 100% 50% ; */
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
}

#izq {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 60vh solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
 border-left: 50vw solid rgb(252, 1, 1);
 border-bottom: 40vh solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
 /* border-image: url(../../assets/img/izq.jpg) 100% 45% 50%; */
 border-image-repeat: round;
 z-index: 1;
 position: absolute;
}

#der {
 height: 0;
 border-top: 60vh solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 border-right: 50vw solid #010ae8;
 border-bottom: 40vh solid #010ae8;
 /* border-image: url(../../assets/img/der.png) 50%; */
 transform: translate(100%);
 z-index: -1;
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width: 100vw;height: 100vh;background-size: contain;background-repeat: no-repeat;">
        <div class="d-lg-flex" id="arriba2" style="background-size: cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
        <div class="d-lg-flex" id="izq" style="background-size: cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-image: url(&quot;assets/img/vetlogo.png&quot;);"></div>
        <div class="d-lg-flex" id="der" style="background-size: cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-image: url(&quot;assets/img/vetlogo.png&quot;);"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Pero cuando quiero agregar las imágenes queda todo mal, y ahí no se como se hace.

Comment: Y lo que has intentado es...? Recuerda que debes agregar en tu pregunta el código con el que has probado y si tienes errores concretos. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) de SO para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echale un ojo a **clip-path**

Con ello podrás recortar las imágenes bastante a tu antojo, pero ojo! no es compatible con ciertos navegadores (los de siempre vamos).

Puedes echarle un ojo a la documentación de mozzila [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) pero creo que lo entenderás muchísimo mejor trasteando con [este](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) generador.

```css
#arriba2 {
  background-image: url('https://data.whicdn.com/images/190300184/large.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 0, 50% 50%, 100% 0);
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

#izq {
 background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/42/f8/be/42f8be8ecaa9507e365ee216f9dcf3d1.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 50% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 100%);
  position:absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

#der {
 background-image: url('https://data.whicdn.com/images/146608104/original.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 50% 100%);
  position:absolute;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width: 100vw;height: 100vh;background-size: contain;background-repeat: no-repeat;">
        <div class="d-lg-flex" id="arriba2"></div>
        <div class="d-lg-flex" id="izq"></div>
        <div class="d-lg-flex" id="der"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```